# Jquery string replacement €

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I use this Jquery code to hide the € symbol on my page.

```
(function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".amount:contains('€')").html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(/(€&nbsp;)/g, '');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

but for some reason I'm unable to get it to work inside WordPress.
I know it has to be in the Document ready function because of the no-conflict mode.
So that is what I have done.

This code is in the same js file i use for other scripts loaded on the same page;

```
(function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".amount:contains('€')").html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(/(€&nbsp;)/g, '');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

(function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("ready to use!");

        if(jQuery('.single-product').length > 0) {
            var _sfm_brand = '';
            var _sfm_model = '';
            var _sfm_generation = '';
            var _sfm_engine = '';
            var _sfm_engine_ecu = '';       
        
            function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                    }
                return vars;
            }
            _sfm_brand = getUrlVars()["_sfm_brand"];
            _sfm_model = getUrlVars()["_sfm_model"];
            _sfm_generation = getUrlVars()["_sfm_generation"];
            _sfm_engine = getUrlVars()["_sfm_engine"];
            _sfm_engine_ecu = getUrlVars()["_sfm_engine_ecu"];
        
            
            
            if(typeof _sfm_brand !== "undefined" && _sfm_brand != "") {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_0"]').val(decodeURIComponent(_sfm_brand));
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_0"]').prop('readonly',true);
            } else {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_0"]').val('');
                
            }
        
            
            if(typeof _sfm_model !== "undefined" && _sfm_model != "") {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_1"]').val(decodeURIComponent(_sfm_model));
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_1"]').prop('readonly',true);
            } else {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_1"]').val(decodeURIComponent(""));
                
            }
        
            
            if(typeof _sfm_generation !== "undefined" && _sfm_generation != "") {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_2"]').val(decodeURIComponent(_sfm_generation));
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_2"]').prop('readonly',true);
            } else {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_2"]').val(decodeURIComponent(""));
                
            }
        
            
            if(typeof _sfm_engine !== "undefined" && _sfm_engine != "") {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_3"]').val(decodeURIComponent(_sfm_engine));
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_3"]').prop('readonly',true);
                
            } else {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_3"]').val(decodeURIComponent(""));
                
            }
        
            
            if(typeof _sfm_engine_ecu !== "undefined" && _sfm_engine_ecu != "") {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_4"]').val(decodeURIComponent(_sfm_engine_ecu));
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_4"]').prop('readonly',true);
                
            } else {
                jQuery('input[name="tmcp_textfield_4"]').val(decodeURIComponent(""));
                
            }
        }       
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

And that code is working great. So I'm sure the file is loaded.

Also, what is strange is when loading the js file by the url I get it like this:

```
(function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".amount:contains('â‚¬')").html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(/(â‚¬&nbsp;)/g, '');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I also tried to change the € symbol with € and u20ac but they are also not working.
Any one who can help me out?

Thank you :)

**EDIT:** in Jsfiddle it is working. And I allready did some other articles, but with no luck. So that is why I'm posting my own.

Comment: Is some of the content being loaded after the page loads such as with ajax? What does `console.log(jQuery(".amount:contains('€')").length)` show? Should not be zero or there are none found

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for the reply. It returns zero (0). I'm using a plugin called TM Extra Product Options and I'm loading the product with a shortcode. The form is in ajax

Comment: Other than using MutationObserver or setInterval to check for that element to exist not sure how things are set up

Comment: @charlietfl The page is: https://webdesignvandaagdemos.nl/demos/chiptuningfiles/?sfid=2150&_sfm_brand=Alfa%20Romeo&_sfm_model=147&_sfm_generation=2001-2005&_sfm_engine=1.6%20T-Spark%20105hp&_sfm_engine_ecu=Bosch%20ME7.3.1 I guess that I have to send a message to the plugin maker. First I tought it has something to do with my jquery code. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress had alot of javascript and php functions loaded, so may one of theme overide or conflict with your codes.

If what you want is hide € character, better add this into your theme's functions.php:

```
 function replace_text($text) {
     $text = str_replace('€', '', $text);
     return $text;
 }
 add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

in case above method not working. Use this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('body').hover(function() {
        let search = '€';
        if(jQuery('.amount:contains('+search+')').html()!=undefined){
            var text = 
 jQuery('.amount:contains('+search+')').html().replace(search, '');
            jQuery('.amount:contains('+search+')').html(text);
        }else{
          return false;
        }
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to use this function but it is not working on my page.

Comment: That mean your theme's template don't have the_content() function in it's loop or using a modified verson of the_content(). So we need to come back to the jQuery solution. I had edited my answer, please using my codes and add it right before body closing tag of your theme's footer.php file. or insert it to your theme before </ body> tag using the "insert header footer" plugin.

Comment: Thank you, this script is working but it also sets all the prices to 1.0. <span class="price tc-price ">
    <span class="amount">&nbsp;1.00</span>
</span>

Answer (score 0):

I also did try to change the currency symbol with an function. But It is not getting the page-template;

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 2 );

function change_currency_symbol( $symbols, $currency ) {
    
    if ( is_page_template( 'archive-chiptuning.php' ) && ( 'EUR' === $currency )) {
        
        return '';
    }

        return $symbols;
}
```

Without is_page_template it is working, but since I use different products, with different currencys (€ and credit(s)) I'm not able to use it like that. Because it changes all the symbols.

**EDIT:** check for page template outside loop:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 2 );

function change_currency_symbol( $symbols, $currency ) {
    
    global $template;
    
    if ( basename( $template ) === 'archive-chiptuning.php' && ( 'EUR' === $currency )) {
        return '';
    }
        return $symbols;
}
```

Use:

```
global $template;
        
        if ( basename( $template ) === 'archive-chiptuning.php'
```

Thanks to this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328384/is-page-template-not-working/375028#375028

Comment: Solved my own problem with the function, with help of this post; https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328384/is-page-template-not-working/375028#375028

Comment: Thank you @Webvd for **Update** this will help others with same problem